# Minimize the time to reach a threshold for a weighted average

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have a $(t,n)$-matrix $A$ with positive entries, such that $s \mapsto A(s,i)$ are increasing functions of time $s=1,\ldots,t$. I would like to find a weight vector $h \in [0,1]^n$ with $h_i$ summing up to 1 that minimizes the time $s$ such that $(A \cdot h)_s$ crosses a given threshold $b>0$.

More precisely, I would like to minimize $\sum_{s=1}^t \text{ind}( (A\cdot h)_s < b )$, where $\text{ind}$ is the indicator function (i.e. 1 if the condition is satisfied, 0 it not).

Questions: What kind of optimization problem is this? Does it have a name? Can this be transformed into a convex problem?

Comment: I think this can be formulated and solved as a MILP (Mixed-Integer Linear Programming problem). Use indicator constraints or Big M modeling to determine which inequalities are satisfied., and minimize the sum of those indicator variables, subject to constraints that weights are nonnegative and add up to 1, or whatever the constraints are on those.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting comment @MarkL.Stone! Still I don't quite understand your idea. The indicators are functions of the variables $h$, so their change during the optimization.

Comment: The indicator variables are binary optimization (a.k.a. decision) variables which are added to the problem.. Linear constraints are formulated and added to the model to enforce the desired implications. Some modeling languages 9packages) make this easy to do. i dom't feel like writing it all out, hence I didn't submit an answer.

Comment: You ought to tbe able to find out how to do this by looking at the relevant links in https://or.stackexchange.com/search?q=conditional+constraints  or https://or.stackexchange.com/search?q=logical+constraints

Comment: Thanks @MarkL.Stone !